# call perl script in cygwin

Tags: windows, perl, cygwin

I would like to start perl.pl within a cygwin terminal such that perl.pl starts in a new cygwin terminal.

What is the best way to do this?

So far I've tried to use system(perl.pl) and exec(perl.pl), but that runs the perl script within the windows command line, not cygwin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see by viewing the properties of the shortcut, the command that opens the terminal is

```
mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -s 105,60 -
```

So you'd run

```
system('mintty perl.pl');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use command xterm:

```
xterm -hold -e perl.pl
```

Comment: This answer is only helpful if you have installed all of the X packages.